# How to prevent an OTA update from being installed?

Tags: updates

How to prevent an OTA update from being installed?

I tried all tips to remove the OTA update notification for lollipop 5.1.1, none worked.

Still, that pops up and has a big install button near the home phisical button, that I am scared of misspressing being forced to install it even if I am in a hurry...

So, how to prevent it from working at all without rooting? Is it possible at all?

Model: samsung galaxy j7

Wont work screenshots (mixed as I can use only 2 links):
[image]

Comment: can  you just turn off notifications from google play services?  you won't get the notification.  that's how i've always done it.

Comment: @fady if I disable the google play services notifications, the ota update notif will remain there :(

Answer (score 0):

The dirty way to do that is to fillup your internal storage with several copies of any 100mb file.

As soon you are low in free space (here is about 400 to 500) that popup with the big install button will show no more, but even if it does, it wont be able to proceed.
This seems to work better after a reboot. The message with install button seems gone now!

And If you need some space, just delete some of these temp files.

Comment: It is fun how something that works is voted down only because ppl are not open minded to accept a workaround even if they dont have a better working solution...

Comment: The best way to quickly duplicate big files is to keep one video file of about 100mb in a tmp1 folder, then copy it to a tmp2 folder using the app QuickPic as it auto renames duplicate files making the this process painless and even fun!

Answer (score 0):

Goto **Settings** then **Apps**

click the option menu and select **Show System Apps**

Search **System Updates** in the app list and click on it.

After that uncheck the option **Notifications**

If you want permanent solution  **Force Stop** the System Update app and **Disable** it.

Hope this will get your work done.

Comment: There is no system apps here: settings / applications / application manager / all. There is no system updates either, there is only two software update of different versions, both active, and neither allow disabling their notifications...

Comment: On both, force stop is also disabled, and their icon is the same of the ota notification

Comment: Try long press click on notification then select don't show any notification

Comment: There is no such option.